Does Appian provide a REST API or SDK to retrieve a list of application names?
I’m working on integrating Appian with a C# application and I need to retrieve a list of application names from my Appian environment.
Could anyone tell me if Appian provides a REST API or an SDK that allows for this functionality? Specifically, I’m looking to:

Retrieve a list of all application names from Appian.
Use this data in a C# application.

If there is a REST API available, could you provide details on the endpoint and any necessary parameters? Alternatively, if there is an SDK or another method to achieve this, I’d appreciate guidance on that as well.
Thanks in advance for your help!
